# Issue in replace the "N-" to "-N" in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
vUnique = NewDF['Quantity'].unique()
for a in vUnique:
    if str(a).find('-') !=-1:
        vRemove = str(a).replace('-','')
        NewDF['Quantity'] = NewDF['Quantity'].str.replace(a,'-'+vRemove)
```

While replace the data into "N-" to "-N" most of Quantity values become NaN values.

please ignore the indentation.
I am new to python, please share your thought's.

Comment: You can't say "ignore the indentation".  Indentation is CRITICAL in Python.  Take the time to do your code right in these questions, otherwise we can't be sure of your intent.

Comment: Now, what exactly are you trying to do here?  Show us what data you're starting with, and what you want at the end.

Comment: i need to replace the values in Quantity columns 
Like : if value coming as "7-", need to updated as "-7"

Answer (score 0):

A string isn't a number (NaN = Not a Number).
You have to parse a string with *int(yourString)* to make it one.
If I understand you right, you have a string that is formatted like "N-", where N can be any number. And the result should be formatted as "-N", but as an int/float.

```
a = "10-"; 
if str(a).find('-') !=-1:
    a = "-" + str(a).replace('-','')
    a = int(a)
    print(a)
```